# Multiple colours for one element

Tags: html, css, colors, webfonts

I'm writing a site where the logo's going to be a word where the middle characters are a different colour to the outer ones; e.g.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen>
    .logoG { color:blue; }
    .logoGo { color:red; }
    .logoGoo { color:yellow; }
    .logoGoog { color:blue; }
    .logoGoogl { color:green; }
    .logoGoogle { color:red; }
</style>
<span class="logoG">G</span><span class="logoGo">o</span><span class="logoGoo">o</span><span class="logoGoog">g</span><span class="logoGoogl">l</span><span class="logoGoogle">e</span>
```

I want to keep the text as text; not use image substitution tricks to hide the text and replace it with a logo background image.  i.e. I want the HTML to look like this:

```
<span class="logo">Google</span>
```

...and for the CSS to do the hard work by doing something along the lines of:

```
logo {visibility: none;}
logo:after {visibility: visible; content: "G"; color:blue;}
logo:after:after {content: "o"; color:red;}
logo:after:after:after {content: "o"; color:yellow;}
logo:after:after:after:after {content: "g"; color:blue;}
logo:after:after:after:after:after {content: "l"; color:green;}
logo:after:after:after:after:after:after {content: "e"; color:red;}
```

...or better yet:

```
logo:first-letter  {color:blue;}
logo:nth-letter[2] {color:red;}
logo:nth-letter[3] {color:yellow;}
logo:nth-letter[4] {color:blue;}
logo:nth-letter[5] {color:green;}
logo:nth-letter[6] {color:red;}
```

So far the closest trick I've found is this trick for rainbow text: http://rainbowcoding.com/how-to-create-rainbow-text-in-html-css-javascript/

I'd also ideally like this solution to avoid javascript if possible; too much?

**UPDATE**

Here's some sample code which works based on hacking the rainbow - however the moment you resize the text (e.g. ctrl + +) it quickly breaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Google Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    h1 {
        background-image:-webkit-gradient( 
        linear, left top, right top
        , color-stop(0, blue)
        , color-stop(0.018, blue)
        , color-stop(0.018, red)
        , color-stop(0.030, red)
        , color-stop(0.030, yellow)
        , color-stop(0.040, yellow)
        , color-stop(0.040, blue)
        , color-stop(0.054, blue)
        , color-stop(0.054, green)
        , color-stop(0.058, green)
        , color-stop(0.059, red)
        , color-stop(0.108, red)
        );
        color:transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;      
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body lang="en-US">
<h1>Google</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure CSS solution is to use a gradient background colour to

- create your rainbow (`background-image: linear-gradient(to left, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red);`)
- use `-webkit-background-clip: text;` to apply this background only behind text (the actual characters; not the non-character pixels around them)
- make the text transparent (`color: transparent;`) so that you can see the background behind those characters.
- Ensure the width of the background matches the width of the text; since if the gradient takes the full page width whilst the text is just a few chars on the left of the page, you'll only see the left-most colour(s).  This can be done via `width: fit-content;`.

```css
.rainbow-text {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Details and example here: https://w3bits.com/rainbow-text/

Note: This isn't one colour per character; rather it's a continuous gradient of colours through all characters

---

ps. Here's a javascript version for anyone with a similar issue but no js concerns.  This uses Jesse's trick of nth child alongside some code to put the relevant tags in play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Google Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    h1 .x:nth-child(1) { color: blue; }
    h1 .x:nth-child(2) { color: red; }
    h1 .x:nth-child(3) { color: yellow; }
    h1 .x:nth-child(4) { color: blue; }
    h1 .x:nth-child(5) { color: green; }
    h1 .x:nth-child(6) { color: red; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function fancy() {
        var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        for(var i = 0; i < h1s.length; i++) {
            var h1Text = h1s[i].innerText;
            var h1InnerHTML = '';
            for(var j = 0; j < h1Text.length; j++) {
                h1InnerHTML += '<span class="x">' + h1Text[j] + '</span>'; //nb: innerHTML is a dodgy hack, but fine for demos / works in Chrome
            }
            h1s[i].innerHTML = h1InnerHTML;
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body lang="en-US" onload="fancy();">
    <h1>Google</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try nth-child() in css. check this link out: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

be careful with n-th-child in css i think IE support is ie9+

span:nth-last-child(2) {
    color: green;
}

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  Sadly that doesn't behave as required (see here for an example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-last-child_odd_even)

Comment: each letter would need to be an html element unless you splice like john did above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without wrapping each letter in some sort of a tag so you can target it with CSS, or using JavaScript. Interesting problem though...